# How to export empty datatable to excel in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, database, datatable

I have no records in my table but still I want to export the null datatable in excel... I can't find a solution please help.

Comment: Do you want this because of the column titles?

Comment: Yes sir, I just want the title to be displayed and the columns be empty.

Answer (score 1):

If a file of type *.csv is acceptable you can do this:

```
 public void writeColumns(System.Data.DataTable table, string filepath)
 {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            sb.Append(col.ColumnName + ";");
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filepath, sb.ToString());
 }
```

Pass over the DataTable and the columns will be written into the file separated by semicolon. You can open this with Office Excel and the columns will be displayed.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2"));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3"));

writeColumns(dt, @"c:\yourdirectory\table.csv");
```